# How to create two parent controllers in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I want to create two parent controllers: one for admin and one for user site. They have to extend a regular Controller class but each of them has to do different things.

Comment: what about a bit more information? do you want do do something like mydomain.com/admin/do_this and mydoman.com/user/do_that ?

Comment: or is it more a conditional extension that you need like in mydoman.com/iamhere/do_taht where the controller Iamhere does a conditional extension so that if it is an admin it extends admin_controller and otherwise it extends user_controller ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote up an article showing how you do this.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

You need to create an __autoload() function in your config.php or directly include the base controller above the class definition.

Comment: link is dead, here's the working one http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy. Do the following:

1. Go to the following directory: `your_ci_app/application/core/` and create a php file called `MY_Controller.php` (this file will be where your top parent classes will reside)
2. Open `MY_Controller.php` and add your multiple classes, like so:

   ```
   class Admin_Parent extends CI_Controller {
       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       public function test() {
           var_dump("from Admin_Parent");
       }
   }

   class User_Parent extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       public function test(){
           var_dump("from User_Parent");
       }

   }
   ```
3. Create your children controllers under this directory `your_ci_app/application/controllers/` . I will call it `adminchild.php`
4. Open `adminchild.php` and create your controller code, make sure to extend the name of the parent class, like so:

   ```
   class Adminchild extends Admin_Parent {

       function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       function test() {
           parent::test();
       }

   }
   ```