# How to create multiple MX Controller (Base controllers) in codeigniter 2.2.2

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance, extends

im trying to create a base controller for some controllers.

Im extending MY_Controller from CI_Controller on application/core. I have a folder named "ajax" in application controllers and i pretend to create a parent class and extend from ajax/classes. Extending all from MY_Controller.

Some like this

```
class Ajax extends MY_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
       blablabla
    }
}

class Ajax extends MY_AJAX{
    public function __construct(){
       blablabla
    }
}

class user extends Ajax{
     blablabla
}
```

Is it necessary to use includes, load_class, etc. or are there another "legal" way to do that?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED YET:

[How to create two parent controllers in Codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913036/how-to-create-two-parent-controllers-in-codeigniter)

This works for me:

```
class MY_Ajax extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        CI_Controller::__construct();

    }

}
```

Comment: Note: call parent class using class reference as you need.

If you has multiple levels you can access to root class using parent constructor.